# How to merge multiple dataframes with unique field names into a single dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I'm trying to merge 5 dataframes into a single dataframe. Each individual dataframe has the same format, the only variation is the column name.

```
# Input Dataframes
df1 = df[['id', 'num', 'type_1', 'object_1', 'notes_1']]
df2 = df[['id', 'num', 'type_2', 'object_2', 'notes_2']]
df3 = df[['id', 'num', 'type_3', 'object_3', 'notes_3']]
df4 = df[['id', 'num', 'type_3', 'object_3', 'notes_3']]
df5 = df[['id', 'num', 'type_3', 'object_3', 'notes_3']]
```

Each time I try to combine them, I accidentally combine them together as columns instead of rows. My goal is to have generate a df with 5 rows

```
# my attempt
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4, df5], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

outputs: `[type_1, type_2, type_3, type_4, type_5, note_1,notes_2...]`

```
# Desired Output Dataframe
final_df = df[['id', 'num', 'type', 'object', 'notes']]
```

It's mildly embarrassing that I don't know how to solve this with concat(), since exactly what I want to do is the very first example in the [pandas .concat() documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html). Can anyone provide guidance? I feel like I'm almost there.

Comment: `concat` uses the column names to know where to put the data. If the dfs don't share column names, it will create a new column and fill with `nan`, is that what you happens to you?

Comment: I think you want to `concat` along `axis=1` and then you can use `pd.wide_to_long` with `stubnames=['type', 'object', 'notes'], sep='_'`

Comment: Can you provide an example of what `df` looks like?

Comment: Rename the columns in df1... df2 to 'type', 'object' and 'notes, then, `pd.concat`.

Comment: @Alollz This is very close.  final_df = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['type', 'object', 'notes'],sep='_', i='X', j='ID_Test')  I get the error that 'X' is not an index, no matter what I put into the parameter. I checked all the indexes in the dataframe and none of them work

Comment: It's hard to really know what you need here, without some sample data (even just two frames with 3-4 rows each) and the expected output. Scott Boston's solution may suffice, and is elegant if you don't care about things like the # after the _, which it seems you dont. I think to make `pd.wide_to_long` to work, you may need to specify `i=['id', 'num']` or perhaps just the ID. This is all conjecture since I'm not quite sure if there needs to be any real index to join on.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @scott-boston and @alollz. I think you both are right but I was able to get it to work with Scott's suggestion. Thank you all.

```py
# rename columns
    d1 = df1a.rename(columns={'id':'id',\
                         'num':'num',\
                         'type_1':'type',\
                         'object_1':'object',\
                         'notes_1':'notes',}
#concatenate
    frames = [d1, d2, d3, d4, d5]
    result = pd.concat(frames)
```